Private Networks via Kurtosis data leak
I deployed a new blockchain on a VM as in example from: https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/kurtosis#prerequisites
It works as I would but there are still some issues. I'm not a great sysadmin yet so I cannot understand what is going on.
It often experience bandwidth peaks and my blockchain communicates with IPs I don't know.
It often experience resources peaks when all the clients are active.
I attach two screenshots coming from command htop:

and from command iftop:

Is that a regular behaviour or is there something weird?

Without more details it seems quite normal for a public blockchain node. It is connecting with other nodes of the network to exchange blocks and transactions. In any case you should put a firewall and other protections for a server facing public interactions.
